# Angle bisector theorem for computing an angle

Tags: geometry

> Trianlge $ABC$ has $AB = 33, AC = 88, BC = 77.$ Point $D$ lies on $BC$ with $BD=21.$ Compute $\angle BAD.$

By the angle bisector theorem we have $\frac{21}{56} = \frac{33}{88}$ and we know that $AD$ bisects $\angle BAC$. Now from here I was able to use the law of cosines, but it resulted in a pretty ugly looking expression $$77^2 = 33^2+88^2-2(33)(88) cos(\angle BAC)$$ from here I was pretty much forced to use a calculator to figure out that $$\angle BAC = 60 \Rightarrow \angle BAD = 30.$$

After looking at the solution they had a very similar approach, but instead of $$77^2 = 33^2+88^2-2(33)(88) cos(\angle BAC)$$

they had $$7^2 = 3^2+8^2-2(3)(8) cos(\angle BAC)$$

which I don’t really get. How can you take one digit of from every term there?

Comment: *"How can you take one digit of from every term there?"* ... Divide-through by $11^2$. So, $$\frac{77^2}{11^2}=\left(\frac{77}{11}\right)^2=7^2 \qquad \frac{33^2}{11^2}=3^2\qquad \frac{88^2}{11^2}=8^2 \qquad \frac{33\cdot 88}{11^2}=\frac{33}{11}\cdot\frac{88}{11}=3\cdot 8$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a question of geometry.....its simple arithmetic:

$$77^2=33^2+88^2-2(33)(88)cos(\angle BAC)$$

Here you can see every term has a factor of $11^2$.

$$(11^2)7^2=3^2(11)^2+8^2(11)^2-(11^2)2(3)(8)cos(\angle BAC)$$

You can cancel out this factor by dividing by $11^2$ on both sides.

$$7^2=3^2+8^2-2(3)(8)cos(\angle BAC)$$